# How to get a child table records which exist in results of a table valued function

Tags: sql

I have a table named TBL_WorkOrder as below :

```
+----+------------+----------------+  
| Id | SystemCode | WorkOrderTitle |  
+----+------------+----------------+  
|  1 | C001       | Title 1        |  
|  2 | C002       | Title 2        |  
|  3 | C003       | Title 3        |  
+----+------------+----------------+
```

and another table named TBL_WorkGroup

```
+----+---------------+
| Id | WorkGroupName |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | WorkGroup1    |
|  2 | WorkGroup2    |
|  3 | WorkGroup3    |
+----+---------------+
```

Each work order can contain different work groups as below (TBL_WorkOrderGroup)

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| Id | WorkOrderId | WorkGroupId |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |           3 |
|  3 |           2 |           1 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

The problem is that I send a varchar string like '1,3' to the stored procedure. This varchar is changed to a table using a table valued function. I want to obtain the work orders that contain both '1' and '3' as their work groups.

What should i do in this case?

Comment: Do you split '1,3'..?

Comment: yes I split '1,3' using a table valued function and return it as a table. Now i want to know the select statement to return work orders which contain both '1' and '3' as their work groups.

Comment: check my posted code, is it provide your expected result?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. You've already got two product specific answers - hope they didn't wasted their time...

Comment: SQL Server. Those answers didn't helped me to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = '1,3'
;WITH Split AS
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,CHARINDEX(',',@String)) SplitStr,SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX(',',@String)+1,LEN(@String)) RemainStr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr) = 0 THEN RemainStr ELSE SUBSTRING(RemainStr,0,CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr)) END,
         CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr) = 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(RemainStr,CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr)+1,LEN(RemainStr)) END
  FROM Split
  WHERE ISNULL(RemainStr,'') <> ''
)
SELECT SplitStr FROM Split
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I've done what you wrote here. I've put this code in a table valued function and return the result as a table. Now i want to know the select statement regarding how to obtain work orders which contain both '1' and '3' as their work groups.

Comment: try this,SELECT * from your_table where Id IN (SELECT SplitStr FROM Split)

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: @Mansoor , Your posted code doesn't work because a work order might not have any group, therefore those work orders won't appear in the result.